# QR Code Event calendar

Tags: google-api

I'm having trouble getting this to scan as a VCAL, right now its scanning as a text type :

> http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=350x350&chl=BEGIN%3AEVENT%0D%0D%0ASUMMARY%3ADENTAL+APPOINTMENT%0D%0ADTSTART+[Appt_Date]+[Appt_Time]%3A%0D%0A3DESCRIPTION%3ADENTAL+REMINDER%0D%0AEND%3AEVENT%0D%0A

Any ideas or help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "VEVENT" - not "EVENT" - otherwise the scanner doesn't know it's a VCAL.

Here's a valid sample event:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Test
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20120124
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20120125
END:VEVENT
```

So, the chart URL you need to use is:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=350x350&chld=L&choe=UTF-8&chl=BEGIN%3AVEVENT%0D%0ASUMMARY%3ATest%0D%0ADTSTART%3BVALUE%3DDATE%3A20120124%0D%0ADTEND%3BVALUE%3DDATE%3A20120125%0D%0AEND%3AVEVENT%0D%0A
```

Comment: Is there a way to used a variable instead of the numbers meaning use [Appt_Date] instead of using the 201220125 to make it read as a VEVENT instead of TEXT type

Comment: Do you mean that the date should say "7 days after today"?  No.